# This version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 - VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

WHAT I DID:

I opened a maven project in vscode, configure the JRE to JDK 17 according to the following settings.json

```
{
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home":"C:\\Development\\sdk\\openjdk-17_windows-x64_bin\\jdk-17",
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
          "name": "JavaSE-17",
          "path": "C:\\Development\\sdk\\openjdk-17_windows-x64_bin\\jdk-17",
          "default": true
        }
      ]
}
```

I also deleted all other JDK paths (11, 8) from PATH variable. When I issue `where java` in my terminal, it only returns JDK 17, which is what I need. I also set the JAVA_HOME to de desired jdk 17.

THE ERROR:

But when I try to run the main method of a Java class using the Run|Debug link above the method's name, I receive this error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class
file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

When I look at the command that is being run, **for some reason the extension is trying to run using an installed jdk 8**, but I did not find from where this value if coming.

Take a look at the error:

```
$  /usr/bin/env C:\\Program\ Files\\Java\\jre-1.8\\bin\\java.exe -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:60055 -cp C:\\Users\\marco\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cp_63fto1nauu53hkuoxjrssuzfw.jar com.joaomarcos.spring.core.ioccontainer.CacheableApplication 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

WHAT I EXPECTED:
I expect that the java class runs without error with the correct JDK, 17, which is the one in JAVA_HOME and the only in PATH

Comment: `echo %PATH%` and `echo %JAVA_HOME%`

Comment: Yes, I did, but nothing about the wrong JDK that is beign used. Will try in cmd,  I did it in bash, but think should be the same. UPD: Nothing in Path and the home is pointing to the jdk 17, that is not beign used when it should.

Comment: We don't know what you did and what were the results. You should share both in your questions.

Comment: I will reformulate the question

Comment: If you're using `JAVA_HOME` then normally you should *pre*pend `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` to `PATH`

Comment: My java env vars are set correctly:

$ java --version returns openjdk 17 2021-09-14. And $ where java returns the correct path to jdk 17: C:\Development\sdk\openjdk-17_windows-x64_bin\jdk-17\bin\java.exe

Comment: That only accounts for `PATH` I'm afraid `JAVA_HOME` can sometimes be important

Comment: Yes. Echo JAVA_HOME is also retuning right to path of jdk 17

Comment: I don't use VS code, but the command beginning */usr/bin/env* (which you should have posted as text *formatted as code* btw) is clearly using Java 8. So if you can't find out where that's being implemented, you could always run it manually with your own command, using env vars

Comment: Yes. I'll post as text formated as code. About rewritting the command using my prefered JDK with the same command, it does not work that way in vscode. The command is automatically generated. I have ways to run that code but it's bad that I cannot figure it out what is happening here.

Comment: Well you certainly need to know what your IDE is doing. My personal experience is that anything your IDE can do, the console can do better and faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved here. I should have entered the configuration in maven build file.

"For projects managed by build tools, Java version is specified in build scripts. E.g. to use Java 8, add below lines in pom.xml"

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

In my case, 17.